# Why docker does not find Env variable to JSON file in the docker container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have problems when I want to add a environmental variable with the path to a JSON file as credentials for `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`

My filesystem is this:

```
Dockerfile
-app
   main.go
   -domain
     go files inside domain folder
   -repositories
     go files inside repositories folder
     firebase-services.json file credentials inside repositories folder
-ui
  html, css, js & images inside ui folder
```

My `dockerfile` is

```
FROM golang:alpine

# Set necessary environmet variables needed for our image
ENV GO111MODULE=on \
    CGO_ENABLED=0 \
    GOOS=linux \
    GOARCH=amd64 \
    GIN_MODE=release \
    GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='/build/app/repositories/firebase-services.json'

# Copy the code into the container
COPY ui /ui/

# Move to working directory /build
WORKDIR /build

# Copy the code from /app to the build folder into the container
COPY app .

# Configure the build (go.mod and go.sum are already copied with prior step)
RUN go mod download

# Build the application
RUN go build -o main .

WORKDIR /app

# Copy binary from build to main folder
RUN cp /build/main .

# Export necessary port
EXPOSE 8000

# Command to run when starting the container
CMD ["/app/main"]
```

I tried everything in `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`, put the relative path, the full path (in my computer), the build folder that I am creating... But when I run the container,  always get the answer of `Failed to create client: dialing: google: error getting credentials using GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable: open /build/app/repositories/firebase-services.json: not a directory`

What I am missing? What should be the path?

Comment: Have you looked inside the container (`docker run --rm -it your-image sh`) to see what the filesystem layout looks like?  Also remember that anyone who gets a copy of the image can trivially retrieve the credentials back out; you should delete the compromised credentials from your source tree, invalidate them, and inject the regenerated credentials using a `docker run -v` bind mount.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Davies, that helped me to solve my problem! :) Also thanks for the extra security tips!